# Do you ever need model releases for your own children?

Tags: legal, model-releases, canada

Location: Canada

I am wondering what is the best course of action for getting a model release form signed for your own children for any work or photos that one person would have. I live in Canada and I know a lot of the laws/rules are different then in the US; but when it comes to model release forms, I seem to keep finding stuff for the US but not for Canada. I am looking to some help or direction on this idea.

I am the photographer that would be doing the work for my children and they are not of age.

Comment: I don't know Canadian law, but I'm guessing since they're your children, and not yet of legal age to sign contracts, that no model release is necessary.

Comment: @digijim i feel like something is actually missing there with no form is required.

Comment: If you need a model release for a publisher, (and again, I know nothing about Canadian law), it stands to reason that you would be the one signing the release, since you're the children's legal guardian.

Comment: I cant be the only Canadian on this page, i can let the question sit open an see what happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did a quick Google of "Canada Model Release Law," and found [this info](https://www.lawdepot.com/law-library/model-and-entertainment-release-faq-canada/#question4_1):

> **Why does it matter if the model is a minor?**
>
> If the model is a minor, he or she will need parental permission to
>   approve of the use of his or her image, likeness, or sound.
>
> **How do you define a “minor”?**
>
> Within the context of the Model and Entertainment Release, a minor is
>   anyone who is legally under the age of adulthood in the jurisdiction
>   where the contract is governed, even if the model is considered an
>   adult in the jurisdiction where he or she lives.

Since you will own copyright to your images, and the subjects will be your minor children, you won't need a model release for your own uses. If you share the images with a publisher or third party that requires a model release, you would be the person signing those releases.

Answer (score 2):

You are the parent, you are the photographer. Unless you plan to sue yourself for using an image then no.  Flippant answer aside i would think that any publication or contest would require a model release form.

Comment: That you would sign yourself!